# base64 decoding not retuning text node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

so i have some code

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    /* parse the url*/
    var q = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    /*de encript it*/
    var base64 = Buffer.from(q.addr, "base64")
    /* JSON encoding*/
    console.log(base64)
    let data = {
        addr: q.addr ,
        base64: base64 ,
    };
    /*outputing*/
    var txt = JSON.stringify(data);;
    res.end(txt);
}).listen(8080);
```

when i go to `http://localhost:8080/?addr=aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=` i expect to see "hello, world" in the console, and this webpage:

```
{"addr":"aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=","base64": "hello world"}
```

but insted i get

> <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64>

and

`{"addr":"aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=","base64":{"type":"Buffer","data":[104,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,108,100]}}`

i understand this is ASCII but how do i get it to display as text. (i want limaler function to the `atob()` feature in client js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `toString` method to the buffer:

```
var base64 = Buffer.from(q.addr, "base64").toString();
```